# React Functional component calling other function or call method from context with some condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem calling function inside functional component below
state.locations.length is automatically increased, and I want if it reach 4 (>3)
I can call function inside context to reset it

since I already **useEffect** for other function, I cannot use it.

the problem how do I put if inside the location that I marked code below

```
  const TrackListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { 
      state, 
      addLocation, 
      fillTrackData, 
      saveTrack,
    } = useContext(LocationContext);  


    const sendTrackAuto = async () => {
      console.log('sendTrackAuto running')
    };

    return <Container>
      <Text h3>{ state.locations.length }</Text>

      // how do I call function sendTrackAuto or saveTrack context 
      // here is what I want 
      // if state.locations.length > 3 then I want call sendTrackAuto or saveTrack automatically without using button keypress

      // below is the one that I think but I don't think it's correct
      { (state.locations.length > 3) ? sendTrackAuto : null }
    </Container>;
  };
```

Comment: Cant't you call it right after declaring it?

Comment: yes I just test it also, but I think using useEffect below is cleaner, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `useEffect` hook to issue side-effect, using the `state.locations.length` in the dependency array. The effect runs when the value of the length updates.

[Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

```
const TrackListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { 
    state, 
    addLocation, 
    fillTrackData, 
    saveTrack,
  } = useContext(LocationContext);  

  const sendTrackAuto = async () => {
    console.log('sendTrackAuto running')
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.locations.length > 3) {
      sendTrackAuto();
      // or do anything else
    }
  }, [state.locations.length]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Text h3>{ state.locations.length }</Text>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you for your example and answer but I forgot to tell you I already use useEffect for other function (I will edit my question), is there other way without using useEffect

Comment: @widjajayd you can have multiple `useEffect`s in one component.

Comment: There are no limits on how many effects a component can have. It isn't like a `componentDidUpdate` class instance function where you can only have one.

Comment: ow ok, let me test your code above, will let you know , thanks

Comment: Just a quick improvement: if you write `[state.locations.length]` useEffect is called every time the var `state` change. If you want to call it only when `locations` change you have to destructure it `const { locations } = state;`

Comment: @MarcoCaldera Not really. Check the link I shared, it describes how passing a deeper property works. `[state.locations.length]` will only fire effect when `length` changes, not the entire `state` object.

Comment: @DrewReese interesting thanks! I read a lot about this but probably I have misunderstood something